# Merging binary files

Tags: svn

I am using svn 1.4.6.

While merging from branch to trunk **binary** files are displayed as being updated in the display but no files are **actually modified**.The binary files were originaly received from trunk into the branch.

Using --ignore-ancestry displays correctly (ie no files are displayed) and no files are **actually modified**.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Lakshman

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this behaviour with word docs in the past.

You may want to double check that the date stamps on the binary files in your checked-out branch are correct. Some binary formats can get tripped just by looking at the file. That would flag them as merge candidates even though they aren't modified.